# C# ThreadPool or BeginInvoke without EndInvoke

Tags: c#, threadpool, begininvoke, fire-and-forget

On the net there a very different opinions on how to implement a fire and forget pattern.

Some say that it is no issue to call BeginInvoke without calling EndInvoke if one has to implement a fire-and-forget pattern.

Others say it's better to create a separate ThreadPool object. My concern is about the ThreadPool initialization cost. Specifically, the the method to call does only add an object to a queue and then returns.

For this, is it "faster" to create a thread on the pool or simply to call the method synchronously? I would like to know a rough threshold of work which is more expensive than to create the thread on the pool.

Are there any documentations on this and what about exception catching on the pool and other restcritions with it?

Comment: If you "simply call the method synchronously" you will not be doing "fire-and-forget".  So I believe your options are ThreadPool, create Thread yourself (var t = new Thread()) or TPL.

Comment: Yes, but the main question was which method is faster. I suppose that I could write simply a measurement and compare the results on average. It may turn out that the synchron call is faster because it will return faster then the call to the static threadpool methdod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the ThreadPool you do not "create the thread on the pool", you use a pre-existing Thread or wait until one comes available.

Only when many jobs are waiting the Pool will add another Thread, but then that one will be well utilized.

Even better to use Tasks (Fx4 and higher).

Comment: So the call to the pool is very cheap compared to the BeginInvoke alternative?

Comment: @BrokenGlass Thanks, that was new to me. The main question still remains: what is the cost of this call?

Comment: Juergen, hard to give an exact answer but the threshold is very low. Using the TP means creating, queuing and invoking a delegate. When your method looks like it does more than that, queue it.